# What am I doing wrong loading my dataset into a bucket?

Tags: python, csv, object, bucket

I am new to Python and taking an an online introductory class in Python for Data Science. I have an assignment to complete which seemed easy and was going well enough until near the end.

Had to web scrape basketball statistics for four players, create dictionaries and then dataframes for each, and finally save, create a URL to share, and share that URL with the instructor.

I have reached this step:

To load your dataset into the bucket we will use the method `put_object`, you must set the parameter name to the name of the bucket, the parameter `Key` should be the name of the csv file and the value for the parameter Body  should be set to `f.read()`.

I have changed the file name around, played with it for hours, and still get various errors. I can't save anything to share until I fix it.  I'm working in Watson Studio. That's where I have my bucket setup. That's where the object needs to be put.  The class has us working in Jupyter notebook.

```
resource.Bucket(name='cahill-pythonbasics-finalassignment').put_object(Key='lebron_james.csv', Body=f.read())
```

I need to put the object in the bucket I created named "cahill-pythonbasics-finalassignment," but instead I get errors.  Most recently the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NoSuchKey                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-391-bcdc2e3a317a> in <module>()
----> 1 resource.Bucket(name='cahill-pythonbasics-finalassignment').put_object(Key='lebron_james.csv', Body=f.read())

/opt/conda/envs/DSX-Python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ibm_boto3/resources/factory.py in do_action(self, *args, **kwargs)
    515             # instance via ``self``.
    516             def do_action(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 517                 response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
    518 
    519                 if hasattr(self, 'load'):

/opt/conda/envs/DSX-Python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ibm_boto3/resources/action.py in __call__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
     81                     operation_name, params)
     82 
---> 83         response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(**params)
     84 
     85         logger.debug('Response: %r', response)

/opt/conda/envs/DSX-Python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ibm_botocore/client.py in _api_call(self, *args, **kwargs)
    251                     "%s() only accepts keyword arguments." % py_operation_name)
    252             # The "self" in this scope is referring to the BaseClient.
--> 253             return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
    254 
    255         _api_call.__name__ = str(py_operation_name)

/opt/conda/envs/DSX-Python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ibm_botocore/client.py in _make_api_call(self, operation_name, api_params)
    541             error_code = parsed_response.get("Error", {}).get("Code")
    542             error_class = self.exceptions.from_code(error_code)
--> 543             raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
    544         else:
    545             return parsed_response

NoSuchKey: An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the PutObject operation: The specified key does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm doing the same Coursera course. I think they mispelled "csv". It's html.
So, instead of "[...] the parameter Key should be the name of the csv file [...]" they meant html.

Answer (score 0):

Try recreating your bucket. I ran into this error initially, but creating a new cross region bucket in `us-geo` solved the issue